# In the Group $(G, .)$, where $G=\{1,-1,i,-i\}$, What is $O(1)$, $O(-1)$, $O(i)$ and $O(-i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the Group $(G, .)$, where $G=\{1,-1,i,-i\}$, What is $O(1)$, $O(-1)$, $O(i)$ and $O(-i)$?

My Answer: 1,2,4,4 is that right?

Comment: That's right. ${}$

Comment: Yes, if everyone is saying O is for order then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$O(x)$ denotes the order of $x\in G$, right? Of course you're right.

Comment: What if we had the group $(Z_{8}, +_{8})$ what are O(4), O(3) and O(2)? My answer is 2,8,4 is that right?

Comment: Right again. What confuses you? You know what's order, yes?